# How to use Nimbus Roman font in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, latex

To match the font of my text in LaTeX, I want to use `Nimbus Roman No9 L` in matplotlib.

I check my LaTeX PDF and pdffonts returns:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SRVJHK+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
LXAKKR+NimbusSanL-Regu               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      12  0
ZNRHEK+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      16  0
```

I thought it would be straightforward to switch fonts in matplotlib.

I attached a minimal example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({
    'font.family': 'serif',
    'font.serif': 'Times New Roman',  # 'Nimbus Roman No9 L',
})

plt.bar(['A ($1+1$)', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3], align="center")

plt.savefig('minimal_example.pdf')
plt.show()
```

When I try to load Nimbus Roman No9 L I always get an error message:

```
WARNING:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: Font family ['serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
WARNING:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: Generic family 'serif' not found because none of the following families were found: Nimbus Roman No9 L
```

Times New Roman loads, but not for the $$ part.

```
> pdffonts minimal_example.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TimesNewRomanPSMT                    Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      21  0
DejaVuSans                           Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      15  0
```

How can I use the same font in my plot as in my text?

edit:
I am able to load Nimbus Roman No9 L, it is called `NimbusRomNo9L`.

```
plt.rcParams.update({
    'font.family': 'NimbusRomNo9L'
})
```

but the math formula still uses DejaVuSans

```
> pdffonts minimal_example.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
NimbusRomNo9L-Regu                   Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      14  0
DejaVuSans                           Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      28  0
```